# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IDownstreamApi'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

Create New

[image]

Using Authentication Type: Identity Platform
[image]

I used a wizard to create a new app registration that added configuration to my Program.cs and settings to my appsettings.json.

> My Program.cs

```
 public class Program
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

         var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

         // Add services to the container.
         builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
         .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
         .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
         .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

         builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
         {
             var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                 .Build();
             options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
         });
         builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
             .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

         var app = builder.Build();

         // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
         if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
         {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
             // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
             app.UseHsts();
         }

         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseAuthorization();

         app.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "default",
             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         app.MapRazorPages();

         app.Run();
     }
```

> My appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "TenantId": "myTennantIdGUID",
    "ClientId": "MyClientIdGUID",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "Client secret from app-registration. Check user secrets/azure portal. In Secrets.json",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": [
      "access_as_user"
    ]
  }
}
```

When it runs:

[image]

Click Accept:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IDownstreamApi' while attempting to activate 'Hub.Controllers.HomeController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IDownstreamApi' while attempting to activate 'Hub.Controllers.HomeController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)
lambda_method16(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
```

[image: Headers]

> HomeController.cs

```
using Hub.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions;

namespace Hub.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDownstreamApi _downstreamApi;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, IDownstreamApi downstreamApi)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient; ;
            _downstreamApi = downstreamApi; ;
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")]
        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            using var response = await _downstreamApi.CallApiForUserAsync("DownstreamApi").ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var apiResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                ViewData["ApiResult"] = apiResult;
            }
            else
            {
                var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                throw new HttpRequestException($"Invalid status code in the HttpResponseMessage: {response.StatusCode}: {error}");
            };
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            ViewData["GraphApiResult"] = user.DisplayName;
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Had a look at a similar issue reported here:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51913

And I added the [Services](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51913#issuecomment-1915865372)

```
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

But it made no difference.

Any suggestions?

Using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current

Version 17.8.7
```

Comment: make sure you have installed the package Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi.create a concrete class that implements `IDownstreamApi`, encapsulating the logic for calling your downstream APIs.and after that you can regieter in the program file. You could remove the `IDownstreamApi` parameter from your `HomeController`'s constructor and rely solely on `GraphServiceClient` for Graph API calls.